# TukeyHSD adjusted P value is 0.0000000

Tags: r, anova

I just performed a factorial ANOVA, followed by the `TukeyHSD` post-test.  Some of my adjusted P values from the `TukeyHSD` output are `0.0000000`.  Can these P values really be zero?  Or is this a rounding situation, and my true P value might be something like 1e-17, that is rounded to `0.0000000`.

Are there any options for the `TukeyHSD()` function in R that will give output P-values that contain exponents?

Here is a snippet of my output:

```
TukeyHSD(fit)

  Tukey multiple comparisons of means
    95% family-wise confidence level

Fit: aov(formula = lum ~ cells * treatment)

$`cells:treatment`
                    diff         lwr          upr     p adj
NULL:a-KR:a     -266.5833333 -337.887800 -195.2788663 0.0000000
WT:a-KR:a       -196.3333333 -267.637800 -125.0288663 0.0000000
KR:ar-KR:a        83.4166667   12.112200  154.7211337 0.0053485
NULL:ar-KR:a    -283.5000000 -354.804467 -212.1955330 0.0000000
WT:ar-KR:a      -196.7500000 -268.054467 -125.4455330 0.0000000
KR:e-KR:a       -219.0833333 -290.387800 -147.7788663 0.0000000
NULL:e-KR:a     -185.0833333 -256.387800 -113.7788663 0.0000000
WT:e-KR:a        -96.1666667 -167.471134  -24.8621996 0.0003216
```

Comment: In your particular case it's impossible for a p-value to be 0.  But the p-value can be so small that the computer can't tell it apart from 0.  Or it might be that the print method chooses to report the tiny p-value as 0 instead of doing something like '<.000001'.  It is theoretically possible for p-values to be 0 in certain situations but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: Use `options(digits=22)` to show all decimal places. But be aware that numbers smaller than 2e-16 cannot be reliably distinguished from each other or from 0.

Comment: a reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ), or the results of `dput(fit)`, would sure help ...

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!!  @BenBolker provided a nice reproducible example in his answer below that clearly shows what's going on (thus I won't provide one).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: see warning below about resolution of Tukey p-values!!

```
dd <- data.frame(y=c(1:10,1001:1010),f=rep(c("A","B"),each=10))
fit <- aov(y~f,data=dd)
```

The printed p-value is zero:

```
(tt <- TukeyHSD(fit))
##   Tukey multiple comparisons of means
##     95% family-wise confidence level
## 
## Fit: aov(formula = y ~ f, data = dd)
## 
## $f
##     diff      lwr      upr p adj
## B-A 1000 997.1553 1002.845     0
```

But looking at the (abbreviated) output of `str()` shows there's more information there:

```
str(tt)

## List of 1
##  $ f: num [1, 1:4] 1.00e+03 9.97e+02 1.00e+03 2.62e-14
##   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##
```

You can extract the value yourself:

```
tt$f[,"p adj"]
## [1] 2.620126e-14
```

Or as noted in the comments, `print(tt,digits=15)` will work ...

**WARNING**

I decided to dig a little deeper and noticed in digging through the code of `TukeyHSD.aov()` that it relies on `ptukey()`, which in its "Examples" section warns that "the precision may not be more than about 8 digits".  In particular, once the t-statistic is above about 30, the p-value maxes out (mins out?) at `2.62e-14` ...

```
zval <- 10^seq(1,6,length=100)
pval <- ptukey(zval,2,18,lower.tail = FALSE)
par(las=1,bty="l")
plot(zval,pval,log="xy",type="l")
```

[image]

The bottom line is that you can't distinguish among p-values this small at all. You may need to rethink your strategy ...

Comment: If adjusted p value is still zero even after setting options(digits = 30), is it correct to report p value is < `2.62e-14`

Comment: Do you get an actual `tt$f[,"p adj"]` equal to zero?